# Colab - Keras - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, python-3.7

I was trying to train and test a network to recognize numbers using keras mnist dataset , and it works perfectly on my computer, but it does not work in Google Colab.

Notebook settings:

- Hardware accelerator GPU

Notebook code:

```py
%tensorflow_version 2.x

import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as k 
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

batchsize=100
num_clases=10
epocas=10 #10*100 = 1000
filas,columnas=28,28

#Entrada y salida
(xt,yt),(xtest, ytest) = mnist.load_data()

xt=xt.reshape(xt.shape[0], filas, columnas, 1)
xtest=xtest.reshape(xtest.shape[0], filas, columnas, 1)

xt=xt.astype('float32')
xtest=xtest.astype('float32')

xt=xt/255
xtest=xtest/255

yt=keras.utils.to_categorical(yt,num_clases)
ytest=keras.utils.to_categorical(ytest,num_clases)

modelo=Sequential()
modelo.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
modelo.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
modelo.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,3)))
modelo.add(Flatten())
modelo.add(Dense(70,activation='relu'))
modelo.add(Dropout(0,25))
modelo.add(Dense(num_clases, activation='softmax'))

modelo.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['categorical_accuracy'], optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())

modelo.fit(xt, yt, batch_size=batchsize, epochs=epocas, validation_data=[xtest, ytest], verbose=1)

puntuacion=modelo.evaluate(xtest, ytest, batch_size=batchsize)

print(puntuacion)
```

This is the complete error log that Google Colab shows me:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-cac37ad8c603> in <module>()
     45 modelo.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['categorical_accuracy'], optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
     46 
---> 47 modelo.fit(xt, yt, batch_size=batchsize, epochs=epocas, validation_data=[xtest, ytest], verbose=1)
     48 
     49 puntuacion=modelo.evaluate(xtest, ytest, batch_size=batchsize)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 726             *args, **kwds))
    727 
    728     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2967       args, kwargs = None, None
   2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2970     return graph_function
   2971 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3204             arg_names=arg_names,
   3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3207         self._function_attributes,
   3208         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:754 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1012 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:375 call
        return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:425 call
        inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:560 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1012 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:231 call
        lambda: array_ops.identity(inputs))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py:115 smart_cond
        pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py:54 smart_cond
        return true_fn()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:226 dropped_inputs
        noise_shape=self._get_noise_shape(inputs),
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:215 _get_noise_shape
        for i, value in enumerate(self.noise_shape):

    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the input to the Dropout Layer

```
modelo.add(Dropout(0,25))
```

The first parameter takes in the fraction of the input units to drop.
The second is a 1D integer tensor representing the shape of the binary dropout mask that will be multiplied with the input.
I think you meant to just set the first parameter. If you change it to the line below it will run.

```
modelo.add(Dropout(0.4))
```

Another issue is that the input for the validation data has to be a tuple and not an array so change this line as well:

```
modelo.fit(xt, y=yt, batch_size=batchsize, epochs=epocas, validation_data=(xtest, ytest), verbose=1)
```

Output from training and evaluation:

```
Epoch 10/10
600/600 [==============================] - 4s 7ms/step - loss: 0.0225 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9924 - val_loss: 0.0280 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.9933
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0280 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9933
[0.0280386321246624, 0.9933000206947327]
```